# How to secure ethereum data at rest, in transit and in use?

Tags: quorum

How to secure ethereum data at rest, in transit and in use?

Perhaps for data at rest through disk encryption?

For in transit, through end to end HTTPS?

Finally, data in use through the use of secure enclaves?

Has anyone secured ethereum data at rest, in transit and in use successfully?

Nathan Aw

Comment: Can you be more specific? What do 'ethereum data' mean? For example ethereum world state, blocks and transactions are signed and have cryptographics proofs, so in practice they cannot be altered easily.

Comment: I meant the world state. Thanks. Am also looking at private ethereum networks. E.g., Quorum